# how to copy folder structure only with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I want to copy the folder structure only (no data) and preserve the ACL from the source

I know that my code will copy the files over.

```
$sourceDir = "\\Server\Path"
$targetDir = "\\Server2\Path"
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir | Copy-Item -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Container
```

robocopy and xcopy is not allowed in our organization. I don't know why but it's not. I'd rather not use the GUI to manually create folders/subfolders.

Comment: What do you mean by "robocopy is not allowed"? It's a Windows built-in tool. What's not allowed about that?

Answer (score 2):

Using `-Filter {PSIsContainer}` will only copy Directories:

```
$sourceDir = "\\Server\Path"
$targetDir = "\\Server2\Path"
Copy-Item $sourceDir $targetDir -Filter {PSIsContainer} -Recurse -Force
```